# Lambdify doesnt work because of backslash in mathematical symbols

Tags: animation, controls, simulation, numeric, lambdify

I have an impedance controller kinematics, I want to make a simulation in python, but the lambdify function unfortunatelly doesnt work and gives the following error:
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

```
sym.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax", latex_mode="equation")

k, tau, omega_n, m = symbols(r'k tau \omega_{\mathrm{n}} m',positive=True)
mu, eta = symbols(r'mu eta',real=True)
par1 = symbols(r'\omega_{\mathrm{n}}\tau ',positive=True)
t, T, uj = symbols(r't T u_j',real=True)
K_imp,K_ratio = symbols(r'K_{\mathrm{imp}} \tilde{K}',real=True)
xd,xjm1,xb = symbols(r'x_{\mathrm{d}} x_{j-1} \bar{x}',real=True)
x = Function('x',real=True)(t)
dx = x.diff(t)
ddx = dx.diff(t)
q = Function(r'q',real=True)(t)
dq = q.diff(t)
ddq = dq.diff(t)
Q = Function(r'q',real=True)(T)
dQ = Q.diff(T)
ddQ = dQ.diff(T)
qjm1,qic,dqic = symbols(r'q_{j-1} q_j \dot{q}_j',real=True)
K_ratio_subs = {K_imp/k:K_ratio}
K_ratio_subs
```

```
#deriv=lambdify((par1,K_ratio),A.subs(data).subs(omega_n*tau,par1))
k=100
K_imp=0.85
num_eqs=eqs.T.tolist()[0]
display(num_eqs)
variables=[ddq,dq,q,qjm1]
#???
deriv=sym.lambdify((variables,par1,K_ratio),num_eqs)
tnum=np.linspace(0,15,1000)

#initial conditions: ddq=0, dq=0, q=0? 
ic=np.array([0,0,0,0])

#numerical integration
sol_num= odeint(deriv,ic,tnum)
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

I tried double backslash, raw string and so on but nothing works for me.